# Doing something with every segment of list?

Tags: python, list, loops, jython

I'm an python/jython coder. I have an list, which includes players. I have function which sends message to player, but it works only with one specific player. Here it is:

```
player.sendMessage() #sends message to player
player1.sendMessage() #sends message to player1
```

What I want is, to send messages to every player that is in list (at once).

```
#List example
players = ['player', 'player1', 'player2']
```

How do I do that?

P.S. have on mind that that list can have hundreds of players, this is just an example...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the player objects directly by adding them into a list.

```
for p in  [player, player1, player2]:
    p.sendMessage()
```

when you say you want to send the messages all at once you mean simultaneously in parallel?

Comment: I feel dumb now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your list contains instances of Player type (thet have the sendMessage() method)

then you can run:

```
for player in players:
    player.sendMessage()
```